# Merge more then 3 csv files in different JSON objects node-red

Tags: node-red

I have a main.csv file with several lines (for now we can assume 3 lines - first one with the titles and 2 with the data), each data line contains some data + reference to another csv file with other details. I want to read main.csv file line by line, get the file name from each line, get details from another csv file and create unique JSON object for each line of the main.csv.

I have managed to create separate objects for each line of the main.csv, but when I merge them I get first JSON object without details nested object, and the second one with both details object. My flow is here:

```
[{"id":"c1e08c1e.09e96","type":"file in","z":"130a7976.464137","name":"","filename":"/home/ros_test/main.csv","format":"lines","chunk":false,"sendError":false,"encoding":"utf8","x":170,"y":180,"wires":[["cce2b9f5.cf50e"]]},{"id":"37206cf9.513154","type":"inject","z":"130a7976.464137","name":"start","props":[{"p":"payload"},{"p":"topic","vt":"str"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":true,"onceDelay":0.1,"topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","x":110,"y":100,"wires":[["c1e08c1e.09e96"]]},{"id":"cce2b9f5.cf50e","type":"csv","z":"130a7976.464137","name":"","sep":";","hdrin":true,"hdrout":"none","multi":"one","ret":"\\n","temp":"","skip":"0","strings":true,"include_empty_strings":"","include_null_values":"","x":370,"y":180,"wires":[["175217cc.5791f"]]},{"id":"175217cc.5791f","type":"function","z":"130a7976.464137","name":"","func":"var temp = msg.payload;\nvar jsonObj = {};\njsonObj.group = temp.Gruppo;\njsonObj.unit = temp.Unit;\njsonObj.name = temp.Nome;\njsonObj.pointInd = temp.IndicePunto;\njsonObj.point = temp.Punto;\njsonObj.date = temp.Data_Ora;\nvar nestedJsonObj = {};\nvar nesNestObj = {};\nnestedJsonObj.RMedia =  temp.RMedia;\nnestedJsonObj.IMedia = temp.IMedia;\nnestedJsonObj.Energia = temp.Energia;\nnestedJsonObj.Tempo = temp.Tempo;\nnestedJsonObj.punti = temp.punti;\nnestedJsonObj.Ravv = temp.Ravv;\nnestedJsonObj.ResistenzaIn = temp.ResistenzaIn;\nnestedJsonObj.ResistenzaF = temp.ResistenzaF;\nnestedJsonObj.ResistenzaMax = temp.ResistenzaMax;\nnestedJsonObj.ResistenzaMin = temp.ResistenzaMin;\nnestedJsonObj.IstDiMax = temp.IstDiMax;\nnestedJsonObj.TDiSalita = temp.TDiSalita;\nnestedJsonObj.IndCresc = temp.IndCresc;\nnestedJsonObj.TDiDisc = temp.TDiDisc;\nnestedJsonObj.IndDecr = temp.IndDecr;\nnestedJsonObj.DiffResMinMax = temp.DiffResMinMax;\nnestedJsonObj.DiffResMaxEnd = temp.DiffResMaxEnd;\nnestedJsonObj.IndSpruz = temp.IndSpruz;\njsonObj.message = nestedJsonObj;\n\nvar file_name=temp.NomeFile;\nconsole.log(\"TEMP =\" + JSON.stringify(jsonObj));\nmsg.payload = file_name;\nvar msg1 = {payload:jsonObj,topic:\"main\"};\n//var msg1 = jsonObj;\n\nreturn [msg,msg1];\n\n","outputs":2,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","x":520,"y":180,"wires":[["f557afc2.257818"],["1c3a587a.e1fff8"]]},{"id":"5b915b21.4b0ae4","type":"file in","z":"130a7976.464137","name":"","filename":"","format":"lines","chunk":false,"sendError":false,"encoding":"utf8","x":770,"y":60,"wires":[["7520e51d.f51fd4"]]},{"id":"f557afc2.257818","type":"change","z":"130a7976.464137","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"filename","pt":"msg","to":"payload","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":590,"y":60,"wires":[["5b915b21.4b0ae4"]]},{"id":"cc445e4.e3abaa","type":"function","z":"130a7976.464137","name":"merge 2 parts","func":"var temp = msg.payload;\nvar mainPart = temp.main;\nvar details = temp.details;\nconsole.log(\"TEMP =\" + JSON.stringify(mainPart));\nconsole.log(\"Details =\" + JSON.stringify(details));\n/*var corrente = temp.Corrente;\nvar resistenza = temp.Resistenza;\nvar tensione = temp.Tensione;\nvar potenza = temp.Potenza;*/\n\nvar jsonObj = {};\njsonObj = mainPart;\njsonObj.message.details = details;\nconsole.log(\"OBJ =\" + JSON.stringify(jsonObj));\n\nreturn jsonObj;\n\n","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","x":1020,"y":200,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"7520e51d.f51fd4","type":"csv","z":"130a7976.464137","name":"csv to json","sep":";","hdrin":true,"hdrout":"none","multi":"mult","ret":"\\n","temp":"","skip":"0","strings":true,"include_empty_strings":"","include_null_values":"","x":930,"y":60,"wires":[["bf9f2157.030ee"]]},{"id":"1c3a587a.e1fff8","type":"join","z":"130a7976.464137","name":"json merge","mode":"custom","build":"object","property":"payload","propertyType":"msg","key":"topic","joiner":"{}","joinerType":"str","accumulate":true,"timeout":"","count":"1","reduceRight":false,"reduceExp":"","reduceInit":"","reduceInitType":"","reduceFixup":"","x":750,"y":180,"wires":[["cc445e4.e3abaa","6787cd8b.97ee6c"]]},{"id":"bf9f2157.030ee","type":"change","z":"130a7976.464137","name":"set topic","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"topic","pt":"msg","to":"details","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":1120,"y":60,"wires":[["1c3a587a.e1fff8"]]},{"id":"6787cd8b.97ee6c","type":"debug","z":"130a7976.464137","name":"TEST2","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":920,"y":300,"wires":[]}]
```

main.csv example

```
Gruppo;Unit;Nome;NomeFile
5;1;PAZ50WB1;tbl_log_res_1420745212_0.csv
5;1;PAZ50WB1;tbl_log_res_1420763227_1.csv
```

tbl_log_res_1420745212_0.csv example

```
Corrente;Resistenza;Tensione;Potenza
0,717514;3987,835693;2,861328;2,053043
1,507996;1868,296387;2,817383;4,248601
2,237671;1197,970703;2,680664;5,998444
```

Expected result should be two messages, first message like this:

```
{
"group": 5,
"unit": 1,
"name": "PAZ50WB1",
"details":[{ "Corrente":"0.717514",
        "Resistenza":"3987.835693",
        "Tensione":"2.861328",
        "Potenza":"2.053043"
    },
    {
        "Corrente":"1.507996",
        "Resistenza":"31868.296387",
        "Tensione":"2.817383",
        "Potenza":"4.248601"
    },
    {
        "Corrente":"2.237671",
        "Resistenza":"1197.970703",
        "Tensione":"2.680664",
        "Potenza":"5.998444"
    }
    ]}
```

how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It would probably be useful if you can supply some example data to go with this description. Also an example of the output data you are expecting.

Comment: I put all files in github repo. Would it be comfortable for u to check them over there? https://github.com/Miliks/node-red-readCSV

Comment: As a rule, Stack Overflow questions should contain all the relevant information without having to link out to elsewhere (so they are still useful if links break). It should only take a line from each file.

Comment: You still haven't shown an example of what output you are actually expecting.

Comment: Updated also expected results.

Comment: for anyone who facing similar issue i get a help on a NODE-RED forum: https://discourse.nodered.org/t/merge-more-than-3-csv-files/44818

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to post an answer to your own question then accept it.  (but it needs to be a full answer and but just a link to somewhere else)